# How to put a custom Binding object in #Preview in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Xcode gives the error message "Ambiguous use of 'Preview'" for the following code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TileDetailView: View {
    @Binding var tile: Tile  // This is a custom object
    @Binding var isShowingTileDetail: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is a tile.")
    }
}

#Preview {
    let bindingVar = Binding.constant(false)
    let aTile = AMClass(name: "A Tile")
    let bindingTile = Binding<Tile>(
        get: { aTile }
    )
    return TileDetailView(aTile: bindingTile, isShowingClassDetail: bindingVar)
}
```

Please feel free to point out problems with the above code. Thank you.

Comment: Use .constant(…) directly in the call to the view init, no need to declare variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? You can use `.constant` to initialize a `@Binding` property. In case the `Tile` is a protocol, replace it with any implementation class, struct, etc. that conforms Tile.

```swift
#Preview {
    TileDetailView(
        tile: .constant(Tile()), //or TileImpl()
        isShowingTileDetail: .constant(false)
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you need to check the initialize function. It should work. I attached an image as the output.

Comment: Thanks, @son. Yes, that works. I didn't mention that I have some parameters in the initialiser omitted because they have default values. But it turned out those parameters should also appear in the initialisers in #Preview.